# PyCharm doesn't see the 'sympify', while Anaconda does. How to solve?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I try to run very simple thing in PyCharm:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
solve(x**2 - 1, x)
```

It doesn't work. I get an error massage:

> from sympify import sympify ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympify'

I have Anaconda Navigator installed. It says that I have "sympy" installed.

Comment: Have you named your script sympify?

Comment: Nope. The script named "MainRun.py"

Comment: Have you configured pycharm to use python from anaconda in **Setting > Project interpreter**?

Comment: If it said that `sympy` is installed but Pycharm say no, there is highly chance that `sympy` was not installed within the same environment as pycharm interpreter is. You can check it out by `pip show sympy` and compare the result with pycharm python interpreter path. They will not be identical, but should be relevant. If they don't, using the pip that come with your pycharm's python interpreter